# How to force HTTP and stop SSL completey on Wordpress website

Tags: redirect, ssl, https, http

We have a Wordpress website wich uses Video files from a local sever without SSL. If we use SSL on the main website url, it can't play Videos because of CORS policies so we need to completely disable the SSL and run the website on http not on https.
We have already disabled the SSL from hosting cpanel and replaced all urls from https to http in Wordpress, also the Site Url and Wordpress URL in setting page is all in http but when we open the url, it force to https even if we put the http:// directly.
In permalinks page all links start with https instead of http. We already deleted the .htacess file and replaced it with a fresh one but no effect on the result.
What should we do to completey run the website without ssl and only http?

Answer (score 0):

You can force it in the .httaccess file

```
# Force HTTP
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: But it causes `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` Error.

Comment: Try In the "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" fields, replace "https://" with "http://".

In Settings General

Comment: Already did all this staf but didn't work!